# 2 ** 256 BigInteger in javascript

Tags: javascript, biginteger

Which will normally result in 1.157920892373162e+77 ,but what I want is the accurate number of 2 ** 256 like 1157920892731685487456125.....

I has try big-integer and math.js but both can't show all of the number after calculate.

Comment: why negative? no code for you to read?

Comment: Yes. Questions about code not working should have code in them, ideally a re-create.

Comment: Paste 2 ** 256 in chrome console isn't it?
And it's not about code not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine using `big-integer`:

```
const bigInt = require('big-integer');
let value    = bigInt(2).pow(256);

console.log(value.toString());
// 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

Comment: With large numbers like that, you can't use the built-in JS methods for calculation (which are limited to what JS itself is limited to), you have to use the methods that `big-integer` provides.