# Why does bigInt give different result when calc. pow() (using npm big-integer)? How to decrypt given number?

Tags: javascript, encryption, biginteger

I'm trying to decrypt my encrypted number.

with the function

```
function decrypt(arg){
  let encrypNum =  bigInt(arg).pow(dNum(eNum,eValue)) 
  let result = encrypNum%b
  return result
}
```

In values it looks like this:

The encrypted value is seven.

result = 7.pow(103)%143
and it should return 123 but it still returns 38. I thought that the number was to big so I used the bigInt method but it still returns 38.

The solution for that should be (that below is not a code, its smth like a pseudo code, since I don't know how to write math in sof. Sorry, will work on that) :
7.pow(103) mod 143 = 7.pow(64) * 7.pow(32) * 7.pow(4) * 7.pow(2) * 7.pow(1) mod 143

which equals

113 × 16 × 113 × 49 × 7 mod 143 = 123

But why is my bigInt method not working and why they show different results? If the second method is the correct method how to implement that in a code ?

First code:

```
function decrypt(arg){
  let encrypNum = Math.pow(arg,dNum(eNum,eValue))
  let result = encrypNum%b
  return result
}
```

Comment: What is your `bigInt` function? It doesn't seem to relate to [the `BigInt` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint), that's `BigInt`, not `bigInt`.

Comment: JavaScript numbers have no `pow` function. (Nor do `BigInt`s.) You've tagged [tag:javascript], did you mean something else? Your code otherwise looks like JavaScript, but...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean javascript. It coud of course be that I misunderstand smth. I've found that method here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502194/2-256-biginteger-in-javascript?fbclid=IwAR2UA_DVTwywKazEBdni99WKMCxpzapb5yt8McXrukYBVstHAmRfZB3evbw

Comment: I suggest editing the question to say explicitly that you're using the `big-integer` `npm` module, and also updating your *"result = 7.pow(103)%143 and it should return 123 but it still returns 38."* since that's not valid JavaScript and it's hard to make out what you're doing when it's invalid.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `%` isn't a modulo operator, it's a *remainder* operator, which has implications if you're using negative numbers.

Comment: Done. Sorry, my first question. What I am trying to do is to decrypt my number that equals 7. I use this method -> a = b^c (modulo) n , where b^c is b->power->c

I think it woudl be easier when I show you the first code without the bigint stuff: 

`
function decrypt(arg){
  //let encrypNumber =  bigInt(arg).pow(dNum(eNum,eValue)) //Math.pow(arg,dNum(eNum,eValue))
  let encrypNum = Math.pow(arg,dNum(erNum,eValue))
  let result = encryptedNumber%b
  return result
}

console.log(decrypt(7))
`

Comment: added it to the post.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `%` operator only works on ordinary JS numbers (i.e. IEEE 754 [double-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), not on `bigInt` objects.  So when you try to apply `%` to a `bigInt`, it is first converted to a float.  If the `bigInt` is too large to be exactly represented by a double-precision float, its lowest bits will be rounded off, throwing off any calculations (like `%`) that depend on them.

The general solution is to use the [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js#readme) `.mod()` method instead of the native JavaScript `%` operator.  However, for the specific case of [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), what you *should* be using is the `.modPow()` method, since it's a lot more efficient (at least for the kinds of large numbers normally used for RSA encryption; maybe not for this toy example) than doing the full `.pow()` calculation and then applying `.mod()` to the result.

Here's a Stack Snippet demonstrating these different operations:

```js
console.log('bigInt(7).pow(103) =', bigInt(7).pow(103));
console.log('bigInt(7).pow(103).mod(143) =', bigInt(7).pow(103).mod(143));
console.log('bigInt(7).modPow(103, 143) =', bigInt(7).modPow(103, 143));

console.log('Number(bigInt(7).pow(103)) =', Number(bigInt(7).pow(103)));
console.log('Number(bigInt(7).pow(103)) % 143 =', Number(bigInt(7).pow(103)) % 143);
console.log('bigInt(7).pow(103) % 143 =', bigInt(7).pow(103) % 143);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/peterolson/BigInteger.js@1.6.40/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```

Running the snippet above should produce something like the following output (possibly with minor formatting differences depending on which back-end implementation [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) ends up using):

```
bigInt(7).pow(103) = "1109425442801291991031214184801374366124020697224286512520326098667350170655466324580343"
bigInt(7).pow(103).mod(143) = "123"
bigInt(7).modPow(103, 143) = "123"
Number(bigInt(7).pow(103)) = 1.109425442801292e+87
Number(bigInt(7).pow(103)) % 143 = 38
bigInt(7).pow(103) % 143 = 38
```

---

Ps. The recently proposed [native JavaScript BigInt objects](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/) *do* work with the normal JS arithmetic operators like `%` (although both operands need to be `BigInt`s or you'll get an error).  If your browser supports this feature, the following should also work:

```js
console.log('BigInt(7)**BigInt(103) % BigInt(143) = ' + BigInt(7)**BigInt(103) % BigInt(143) + 'n');
console.log('7n**103n % 143n = ' + 7n**103n % 143n + 'n');
```

On browsers where the code above works, both expressions should evaluate to the BigInt value `123n`.  (Apparently, the Stack Snippets console doesn't yet know how to display BigInt objects properly, so I had to manually stringify them to get the results to show up.)

Unfortunately, the native BigInt proposal doesn't seem to (yet) include a proper modular exponentiation routine.  Thus, for working with modular powers of large numbers, a wrapper such as BigInteger.js (which should automatically use the native BigInts internally if they're available) is still recommended.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Operators mod should work

Comment: @Populus, it does if you're using the native BigInt objects described on that page. The user who asked this question was using [a custom bigint library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) that doesn't enjoy the special syntax support that native BigInts have (in JS versions that support them).

Comment: One thing that's worth mentioning, about older browsers: Usually, it's possible to work round missing globals etc with tools like Babel, and you may already be using this for other language features. But the native `BigInt` can't be added just using a shim, since it requires operator overloads. I don't know whether there's a way round this. So if you're relying on Babel or something for older browsers, you should make sure you can get the native `BigInt` to work before you commit to using it.